# Producer Consumer using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, thread-safety, producer-consumer

My producer-consumer problem runs perfectly for 1 producer and 1 consumer. It fails to run for 2 producer and 2 consumer. It is reaching some unknown deadlock state. I'm not able to debug. Can anyone please help me with it?

Constraint: One Producer has to produce upto 64 items. And consumer runs until it clears all produced items.

---

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

class Producer implements Runnable {
    private static int count = 1;
    private Random rg = new Random();
    private BlockingQueue<Object> queue = null;
    private static int pc = 0;
    static int maxPc = 0;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Object> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (queue) {
                while(pc <= maxPc) {
                    try {
                            produce(pc++);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    public void produce(int pc) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(queue) {
            while(queue.size() == 8) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Buffer full: waiting for consumer");
                queue.wait();
            }
        }
        synchronized(queue) {
            System.out.println("Producer: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " adding item "+ pc + " to the queue");
            queue.add(pc);
            //Thread.sleep(1);
            queue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private static int consumeCount = 0;

    private BlockingQueue<Object> queue = null;
    private Random rg = new Random();

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Object> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
        public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(queue) {
            while(queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Buffer empty: waiting for producer");
                queue.wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized(queue) {
            //Thread.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("Consumer: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+" removing item " + queue.take() + " from the queue");
            consumeCount++;
            queue.notifyAll();
            if(consumeCount == ParallelProcess.maxCC + 1)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}

public class ParallelProcess {
    static int maxCC = 0;
    int numProducer;
    int numConsumer;
    private Thread[] cThreads;
    private Thread[] pThreads;
    private BlockingQueue<Object> queue = null;

    public ParallelProcess(int numProducer, int numConsumer, int queueSize) {
        this.numProducer = numProducer;
        this.numConsumer = numConsumer;
        this.queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Object>(queueSize);

        // create consumer thread objects
        cThreads = new Thread[numConsumer];
        for (int i = 0; i < numConsumer; i++) {
            cThreads[i] = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
        }

        // create producer thread objects
        pThreads = new Thread[numProducer];
        for (int i = 0; i < numProducer; i++) {
            pThreads[i] = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
        }
    }

    public void execute() {

        // start consumer threads
                for (Thread t : cThreads) {
                    t.start();
                }
        // start producer threads
                for (Thread t : pThreads) {
                    //System.out.println("tc");
                    t.start();
                }

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // provide number of producers, number of consumers and the
        // max-queue-length
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  

           System.out.println("Enter no. of producer and conumer");  
           int n = sc.nextInt();  
        ParallelProcess process = new ParallelProcess(n, n, 8);
        maxCC = n*64;
        Producer.maxPc = maxCC;
        process.execute();
        // (new Thread()).start();
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " `enter code here`FINISHED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `jstack` or similar to get a stack trace for all of the threads.  Use that to figure out what threads are deadlocked ... and with some brain cycles ... work out why.

Comment: *I'm not able to debug.* Why not?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should merge `synchronized` block of the `wait` and `queue.add(pc)` to make it automatic, otherwise it might cause some inconstency.

Secondly, you should call `queue.notify` before `wait`, otherwise both `producer` and `consumer` might be blocked in `wait` state.

produce method:

```
public void produce(int pc) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(queue) {
        while(queue.size() == 8) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Buffer full: waiting for consumer");
            queue.notifyAll();
            queue.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Producer: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " adding item "+ pc + " to the queue");
        queue.add(pc);
        //Thread.sleep(1);
        queue.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

consume method:

```
public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(queue) {
        while(queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Buffer empty: waiting for producer");
            queue.notifyAll();
            queue.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+" removing item " + queue.take() + " from the queue");
        consumeCount++;
        if(consumeCount == ParallelProcess.maxCC + 1)
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```